# Dealing with ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous | for multiple conditions in finding indices of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements

When I want to reach to indices of rows with one condition I do:

```
df[df['label'] <= x].index

output: 
Int64Index([   44,    45,    46,    47,    48,    49,    50,    51,    52,
               53,
            ...
            28603, 28604, 28613, 28622, 28623, 28624, 28632, 28633, 28646,
            28647],
           dtype='int64', length=3710)
```

but if I do:

```
df[df['label'] >= y & df['label'] <= x].index
```

I got the Value error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any tips and tricks would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to add parenthsis around each condition `df[(df['label'] >= y) & (df['label'] <= x)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the parethsis or just do `ge` and `le`

```
df[df['label'].ge(y) & df['label'].le(x)].index
```